# Laravel change variable within collection filtering

Tags: php, laravel, collections, scope, filtering

Is there anyway to make `$var = 7` in collection filtering like this?

```
$var = 1;

$collection->filter(function( $q ) use ($var){
    if( true ){
        $var = 7;
        return true;
    }
});

dd( $var );
```

Currently this doesn't work and what I get is still `1`

I've also tried using `global` but still I get `1`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pass the variable [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), then it will get changed, e.g.

```
$collection->filter(function( $q ) use (&$var){
                                      //^ See here
```

Comment: Oh my God, thank you, I was frozen in front of this issue for a very long time, while a tiny `&` fixed it :(